# Can’t delete a folder in Windows Server 2012. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

I am using Windows Server 2012 and I want to delete a folder so I use <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and yes, all the files inside is removed but the problem is the folder still there no matter what method I use.
I tried to use cmd with command

```
rd \S D:\folder_name
```

But it say the error file1; this is the folder I want to delete since its name is too long I just remove the parent folder having shorter name. But then the notice “system cannot fin the file specified” appear. The folder is still there.

The folder name contains just alphabet characters with only extra `[` and `]`
The rename doesn’t work as well because the error couldn’t find item, folder no longer locate at…

Please explain to me what error is this.

Comment: Sometimes certain parts of the UI don't keep up with file-system changes. Have you tried simply rebooting to see if it goes away on it's own? Have you run a CHKDSK to ensure there's no file-system corruption?

Comment: Check that folder has full administrative permission.

Comment: if it's just the UI, why even when Using cmd command can't remove it? I can still move file into that folder like usual

Comment: Use `/S` switch as `\S` is parsed and considered to be a folder or file name `S` under current dirive root

Comment: @aukxn You only mentioned you tried running "RD" in a command prompt, but does the file showup if you run `dir` in that folder? And as JosefZ points out, switch options use a forward slash (`/s`) not a backslash as you've put in your question (`\s`) - was that just a typo?  If not, go try `rd /S D:\folder_name`

Comment: I tried both >/s and >\s since I'm easy to get confused. Both not work. I have just try dir as you say and the folder name still appear.

Comment: Try `rd /S "\\?\D:\folder_name"` with quotes and the ` \\?\ ` prefix if _folder name is too long_. [Read more here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath)

Comment: Undocumented: `rd` command accepts more folders to delete, so if there is a blank space, use quotes as follows: `rd /S "D:\folder_name with space(s)"`